# SSRS remove duplicate row entries

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, repeat

I need to see all the notes but not repeat the name and account number.  Please see the example below.  I'm using SSRS report builder 2008.

This is how it currently looks:

```
Name|Account|Note
John|123456 |note1
John|123456 |note2
John|123456 |note3
John|654321 |note1
John|654321 |note2
John|654321 |note3
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
Name|Account|Note
John|123456 |note1
    |       |note2
    |       |note3
John|654321 |note1
    |       |note2
    |       |note3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you cna try by adding Row group on your tablix.

You need to add first Row group on Name and second row group on Account so it will be look like

```
Name|Account|Note
John|123456 |note1
    |       |note2
    |       |note3
John|654321 |note1
    |       |note2
    |       |note3
```

search for row group you will get result.

check below image

[image]

Comment: If I group on name and account I will only get the first note.

Comment: but for second row group you need to set two column 1. Account and 2. Note

Comment: I have updated my answer with the image. I also created same report at my end

Comment: First of all thanks for your help.  It's so close.  The only issue is that if the name is the same it won't show the duplicate since it's grouping on name.  Any ideas?

Comment: I got it, I had to group on the account number first and then the name and I got the results I needed.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you set hide duplicates property to true for column A and Column B then it shouldn't repeat itself.

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work in my case.  My columns are Name(A), Acccount Number(B) and Notes(C).  I have duplicate names with different account numbers so I need to show some duplicate names.

Comment: From looking at your sample data.. you should be grouping on Name and account.  Then you should get the desired display

Comment: If I group by name I only get the first note.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet.. But what if you derive a concatenated column based on Name+Account group by that column but hide it on the report? Show the rest of the columnist and then hide duplicates within each group?